# Docxpresso library ignores sign & ampersand in render

Tags: php, html

I'm using [the Docxpresso library](https://www.docxpresso.com/documentation-api/quick-user-guide) to render documents. When rendering the text in HTML, the result in the ODT file ignores or eliminates the ampersand sign "&". How can I modify the library so that it does not delete "&"? below I leave my code that I use:

```
$html = '
  <style>
       * {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt}
  </style>

  <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><u>MINUTA >> << &&&</u></strong></p>';

$doc = new Docxpresso\createDocument();
$format = '.odt'; //only .odt because I dont have licence

$doc->html(array('html'=>$html, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

$doc->render('sample' . $format);

header('Location: ../creditogarveh/sample'.$format);
```

I expect the output in archive like: "MINUTA >> << &&&", but the actual output: "MINUTA >>".

Comment: If you want a literal `&` you need to type `&amp;`. That's how HTML works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're outputting to HTML, then special characters `<`, `>`, `&`, and `"` must be escaped. Use the built-in [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function to do this.

Also note [the heredoc format](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) is much better for outputting large blocks of text, especially when dealing with quotes and interpolated values.

```
$value = "MINUTA >> << &&&";
$value = htmlspecialchars($value);
// $value is now "MINUTA &gt;&gt; &lt;&lt; &amp;&amp;&amp;"

$html = <<< HTML
  <style>
       * {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt}
  </style>

  <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><u>$value</u></strong></p>
HTML;

$doc = new \Docxpresso\createDocument();
$format = ".odt";
$doc->html([
    "html" => $html,
    "encoding" => "UTF-8"
]);
$doc->render("sample$format");
header("Location: ../creditogarveh/sample$format");
```